# How can I replace a string in an array with a new string?

Tags: arrays, string, swift, swift2

I am using a for loop to go through an array of strings. For each string, I am finding a new value for it. After finding the new value, I need to replace the string at the corresponding index.

```
var myStrings = [String]()

for var i = 0; i < myStrings.count; i++ {

    let newValue: String = //Do some work to find the new value

    myStrings[i] = newValue //This is what I thought would work, but I'm getting a crash and error saying that the array is out of index.

}
```

The error says that the array is out of index.

Comment: Which line is giving the error? Also, what is in your line creating the newValue? Also, you'd probably be better using a map function for this.

Comment: You can replace `myStrings[i]` with another value, but you can't create a value there if the index doesn't exist.  That is why you are getting index out of range.  Try using `append` to add items to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My work to find newValue involved the use of some closures. I had to redefine `i` as `index` inside a closure to be able to use it inside the closures.